# Read an image like a text, line by line

Tags: c

I have a text file that has a structure like:

```
P2
# CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1
445 243
255
108
107
104
102
102
[...]
```

And i want to read this text file line by line. So i writed this code:

```
int main(void) {

     char str[50];
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("/home/user/Downloads/file.pgm", "r");

        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Testing fgets() function: \n\n");
        printf("Reading contents of myfile.txt: \n\n");

        while( fgets(str, 30, fp) != NULL )
        {
            puts(str);
        }

        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
}
```

However, it gives a strange output. And i don't know where is the error. The code seems ok. What do you think ?

Execution :

[image: output]

Comment: Please put the output in the question and explain what is strange about it.

Comment: "Error opening file" is the canonical example of a bad error message.  `fp=fopen(path, mode);  if(fp == NULL) {perror(path); ...`

Answer (score 1):

You're limiting the `fgets` to 30 chars, and the comment

> # CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1

is 38 characters.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple *fgets* also return the `\n` when it is read (it is not discarded) and writing by *puts* you add an other `\n` after the print, so you have 2 `\n` creating an empty line

Replace  `puts(str);` by `fputs(stdout, str);` and you will not have the empty lines

Note : the *output* doesn't correspond to the beginning of the file, may be its end ?

if I put

> ```
> P2
> # CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1
> 445 243
> 255
> 108
> 107
> 104
> 102
> 102
> ```

in the file the execution gives :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Testing fgets() function: 

Reading contents of myfile.txt: 

P2

# CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Ve
rsion 1.1

445 243

255

108

107

104

102

102
```

one line is cut because has more than 29 characters

Comment: yeah, sorry. noticed that too late. and comment deleted.